# Reading the document immediately after storing it using a transaction in ravendb

Tags: c#, transactions, ravendb

Here i'm storing a document of type transactionSummary using transaction scope as follows

```
public class TransactionSummary
{
[JsonIgnore]
        public Guid? Etag { get; set; }
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String TransactId { get; set; }
        public OpenOrClosed BalanceType { get; set; }
        public TransactStatus Status { get; set; }
        public String PayeeAccountNo { get; set; }
        public Decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
}



using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
{
  using (IDocumentSession sess = GetConnection())
   {
     sess.Store(fldtrans);
     sess.SaveChanges();
   }
    trans.complete();
}
```

after storing it immediately i have a need to retrieve it so i'm doing it as follows

```
   using (IDocumentSession sess = GetConnection())
   {
     sess.Advanced.AllowNonAuthoritativeInformation = false;
     sess.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;
     transact = sess.Query<TransactionSummary>().Where(x => x.TransactId ==transactid).FirstOrDefault();                                                                 
     transact.Etag = sess.Advanced.GetEtagFor(transact);
   }
```

Here I'm getting a exception as follows
   ex = {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key"}StackTrace = "
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)\r\n   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.GetDocumentMetadata[T](T instance) in c...

I understand that it takes certain time to commit the transaction so when the document is read immediately it is getting failed. But how can i overcome this so that i do not sacrificce my requirement.

Matt here i'm doing lot of other work too in that transaction scope i've just shown the glimpse for you to understand one of it is i'm posting the TransactionId to a queue and my background service fetches the transactionId(not the document Id) and does the some other process which needs to be done post transaction.Here what happens is the queue fetches the transactionId earlier before the transaction is being affected in the real database.

This is my Getconnection code for reference.

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
    {
        static IDocumentStore _docStore ;
        public DataAccess()
        {

            _docStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8081" };
            _docStore.Initialize();
            _docStore.Conventions.IdentityPartsSeparator = "-";  

        }

        #region IDataAccess Members

        public IDocumentSession GetConnection()
        {

            IDocumentSession sess = _docStore.OpenSession();
            _docStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists("MyDB");
            return sess=_docStore.OpenSession("MyDB");
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on just what you have shown, there's no need to explicitly define a transaction scope.  There is already an implicit transaction around the unit of work defined by the scope of the session.  The only time you should need to explicitly use `TransactionScope` is if you are making calls to two or more separate databases with different sessions - or calling raven and some other transaction-aware process.

I'm not sure why you would want to query in a new session immediately after storing.  You certainly will have stale index issues to contend with.  If you really must do this, you should probably just load the document by its `Id`.

Perhaps you are not aware of this, but the `Id` is available immediately after calling `.Store()` in your first session - even before you save changes.  And if you want to get the document's etag, you can make the call to `.GetEtagFor()` right after the `.SaveChanges()` call in the first session.  There's really no need to create another session for either of these purposes.

If you haven't already, you should also read [this RavenDB KB article](http://ravendb.net/kb/16/using-optimistic-concurrency-in-real-world-scenarios) about optimistic concurrency and etag issues.  I think you'll find most of your concerns addressed there.

One last thing - please update your question to show the code for your `GetConnection()` method.  It's hard to tell if you are using `IDocumentSession` and `IDocumentStore` properly without showing that.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1811801 - You should probably move `EnsureDatabaseExists` call to the constructor with the rest of the db init code.  no need to make that call with every session.

Comment: @user1811801 - Would it be possible to just use the transaction id as part of your document key?  Then you could avoid the query entirely.  Perhaps something like `transactionSummaries/{transid}` would work well.